# Moving cache to SD Card? Is it possible?

Tags: cache

Is it possible to move app cache which is stored o Internal Storage on android to sd card? I have limited space on my device, and I want to free up some space (Well, actually the cache is taking most of my internal space) by moving my application cache to the SD Card.

Well, i know that cache can be deleted easily, but it's a pain to delete it every few hours to ensure that there's no "Low Memory" notification hanging..
There's also my Browser & Chrome cache, which could fill my Internal Storage in a matter of minutes.

Answer (score 4):

it is possible, but you will need to get a root. 
FolderMount allows to transfer not the apps but their cache. This program requires root access. If you don’t know what root is then go here and here to read about how to gain root access.

Cache transfer is performed in a few simple steps:

```
Open FolderMount and press “+” in the top right corner.
Name an app that has leftover cache in the internal memory.
Press “Source” and indicate the folder with the app’s cache. It is located in Android/obb/the folder with the app’s name.
Press “Destination” to choose a folder on the SD card for the transfer.
After every field is filled out, press the check mark in the top right corner and select the “pin” next to the Name field.
```

Read here http://droidguides.com/applications-to-sd/

Comment: FolderMount becomed a GREAT facility to move out some things and bypass the main problem with Internal/External storage. Not all phones does swap them, and sometimes Internal memory is fullfit with garbage while SDCard remains free. Actually, space for app's and some other things are a total shame. Who needs 8gb free while you cannot install anything else because of factory partitions?

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at our [app2sd](/questions/tagged/app2sd) [tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/app2sd/info), there is a solution to that – but it requires your device to be rooted. *Simple2Ext* ([S2E](http://www.appbrain.com/app/ru.krikun.s2e)) offers to move apps, their data, and some cache to the SDcard.

Alternatively, as cache resides on its own `/cache` partition, you could also use [DirectoryBind](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1410262) to move that to SDcard entirely. Again, this requires root.

Comment: According to Google Play, S2E requires custom firmware.

Comment: @intuited you mean root? it is S2E different than other x2sd app's?

Comment: @erm3nda quoting from the description: "S2E works only with CyanogenMod7, CyanogenMod9 and CyanogenMod10". So: custom ROM. Apart from which, S2E hasn't been updated for about 4.5 years. The last CM was CM13 (now: LOS 13/14). I'm not sure if this app still works on recent versions (note my answer was posted in 11/2013).

Answer (score 0):

You **Should** clean cache regularly, a Lot of cache can make your device Slow, you can use [Auto Cache Cleaner Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.beers_sta.cache_free&hl=en) to Clean all the cache quickly, you can also schedule an automatic clean up too!

Android maintain caches and removes un-needed caches

however, I've read in Google developers docs that the App should maintain the Cache itself and the developer must not rely on Android to maintain the cache

but some Apps doesn't maintain cache as needed, and so you need to clean them, usually Cache shouldn't be more than **~25MB per App**, and shouldn't be more than **~75MB in all the device** (however, it Depends on the number of apps..)